# Virtuoso localhost DESCRIBE results in File not found

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

On my machine I successfully use this address to enter the faceted browser view for a resource:

http://localhost:8890/describe/?uri=http://www.example.org/tf/code/ring1-MONO

I installed Virtuoso on a colleagues Windows machine (similar to mine) and uploaded the same TTL file. When they paste this same address into their browser, they receive the error:

```
Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found

The requested URL was not found    URI  = '/describe/'
```

Our `virtuoso.ini` files are identical and we are running Virtuoso version 7.20.x on Windows 7. Troubleshooting advice would be greatly appreciated!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [install the Virtuoso Facet Browser](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtFacetBrowserInstallConfig) on the second machine? This is what provides the `/describe/` URLs.

Comment: This may be the case. My colleague returns to the office tomorrow and I will update this thread at that time.

Comment: Facet Browser plugin was NOT installed. Entirely my fault. All systems now go and we are hooking in to the view from D3js and RShiny. Thanks!